# Very long timestamp for a backup file created via a Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server, backup, maintenance-plans

I have been using Maintenance Plans to back up my databases. It works well enough for me but I am curious to know why the .bak have a very long date/time suffix. Here is an example:

MyDatabase_backup_2022_10_27_213008_2710399.bak

I can see the yyyy_MM_dd_hhmmss format but what about the rest (2710399), microseconds...?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see the YYYY_MM_dd_hhmmss format but what about the rest (2710399), microseconds...?

Yes, helps makes the file unique. I believe the format string for backups is something akin to: `yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss_fffffff`

Comment: You lead me in the right direction. fffffff are the digits of the fractions of a second, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/booteventcollector/get-sbecbackupconfig?view=windowsserver2022-ps.